# How exactly does !function(){}() work?

Tags: javascript

I've seen:

```
!function(){ //code }();
```

Used in several places to immediately execute an anonymous function.  Normally, it's used in lieu of:

```
(function(){ //code }())
```

Anyone know how the `!` actually makes the function execute?

Comment: It's worth pointing out that while the former works, it does negate the value returned by the function, whereas the second form does not.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

***What the ! does***

When you use `!`, the function becomes the single operand of the *unary (logical) NOT* operator.

This forces the function to be evaluated as an expression, which allows it to be invoked immediately inline.

---

***Other alternatives***

You can do this with just about any operator. Here are some examples...

```
'invoke',function(){ /*code*/ }();
1+function(){ /*code*/ }();
void function(){ /*code*/ }();
~function(){ /*code*/ }();
+function(){ /*code*/ }();
```

Nice thing about some of these is that the meaning of the operator is not overloaded.

---

***The problem with `()`***

When you use `()` around the function, you can hit some bugs that will crop up if you have more than one in a row without a semicolon separating them.

```
(function() {
    alert('first');
}())


(function() {
    alert('second');
}())

// TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

This will result in a `TypeError`, because the pair of outer `()` around the second function will be interpreted as intending to *call* a function. The first one doesn't return a function of course, so you're trying to call on `undefined`.

---

***How using a different operator copes with (or avoids) the problem***

Even an operator like `+`, which is overloaded to some degree won't cause an error.

If you do this...

```
+function() {
    alert('first');
}()

+function() {
    alert('second');
}()
```

The first `+` is interpreted as a *unary + operator*, and it converts the result returned from the first function, which in this case is `undefined` so it gets converted to `NaN`.

The second `+` will be interpreted as the *addition operator*, and so will try to add `NaN` to the return result of the second function, which again here is `undefined`.

The result of course is `NaN`, but it is harmless. There's no illegal code to throw an error.

---

***Demonstration of how the operators interact with the functions***

To prove this, just give each function a return value, then paste it into the console...

```
+function() {
    alert('first');
    return "10";
}()

+function() {
    alert('second');
    return 20;
}()

// 30
```

You'll get the two `alert`s, and then the console will show `30` because the first `+` operator converts the String `"10"` to the Number `10`, and the second `+` added the two results together.

Comment: +1 Great answer and very interesting information.

Answer (score 2):

The `!` is an ordinary logical negation.
The `()` executes the function.

Comment: I think OP is asking why simply prepending `!` to `function(){ //code }()` (which is otherwise an error) causes the anonymous function to be executed.