# What does !function ($) { $(function(){ }) }(window.jQuery) do?

Tags: jquery, jquery-tooltip

I'm using twitter bootstrap to create a site and was trying to initialize tooltips. Apart from adding something like:

```
 $("[rel=tooltip]").tooltip()
```

in application.js ,  unless I retain, the following piece of code used in bootstrap docs, my tooltips don't initialize.

```
!function ($) {

  $(function(){  

  })

}(window.jQuery)
```

What does the above code do?

Answer (score 165, accepted):

Lets explain by Breaking up the code

```
function () {
}()
```

Or often written as

```
(function () {
})()
```

Is a `self-invoking anonymous` function, also known as **Immediately-Invoked Func­tion Expres­sions (IIFEs)**. Which executes the anonymous function inline immediately.

Read more about this at [Explain the encapsulated anonymous function syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1634268/1048572).

Anonymous functions are a powerful feature and have benefits like scoping ("variable name spacing"), see [What is the purpose of a self executing function in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/592396/1048572).

---

Now they are using

```
function ($) {

}(window.jQuery)
```

Let's skip the `!` for now.

So they are passing, `window.jQuery` into that function as argument and accepting as `$`.

What this does is making `$` an alias to `window.jQuery` (original jQuery Object) and hence ensuring that the `$` will always refer to the `jQuery object` inside that `closure`, no matter if other library has taken that(`$`) outside.

So code you write inside that closure using `$` will always work.

Another benefit is that `$` comes as an argument in the anonymous function, which brings it closer in the `scope chain` and hence it takes less time for the JS interpreter to find the `$` object inside the closure than it would otherwise took if we used the global `$`.

---

```
$(function(){  

})
```

It's jQuery's document ready block as you might already know, which ensures that code inside this function will run when `dom is ready`, and hence all `event binding's` will work properly.

Read more at http://api.jquery.com/ready/

And what that `!` does has been well explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611700/how-exactly-does-function-work/8611734#8611734) or at [What does the exclamation mark do before the function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3755606/1048572)

**In Short:**

To demonstrate the benefits of `!`, Lets consider a case,

```
(function() {
    alert('first');
}())


(function() {
    alert('second');
}())
```

If you paste the above code in `console`, you will get two alerts, but then you will get this error

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Why this happens? Let's simulate how JS engines executes the above code block. It executes this anonymous function `function() {alert('first');}()` shows the alert and as it returns nothing `undefined` is returned inside the `()`. Same happens for the second function too. So after the execution of this block, it ends up having something like

```
(undefined)(undefined)
```

and as it's syntax is like a `self-invoking anonymous` function, it tries to call that function, but the first, `(undefined)` is not a function. So you get `undefined is not a function` error. `!` fixes this kind or errors. What happens with `!`. I am quoting the lines from the above answer link.

> When you use !, the function becomes the single operand of the unary
>   (logical) NOT operator.
>
> This forces the function to be evaluated as an expression, which
>   allows it to be invoked immediately inline.

and this solves the above problem, we can rewrite the above block using `!` like

```
!(function() {
    alert('first');
}())


!(function() {
    alert('second');
}())
```

---

For your case you can simply put your tooltip code inside a document ready block like this

```
$(function(){  
    $("[rel=tooltip]").tooltip();  
});
```

and it will work fine.

And if you just use `$("[rel=tooltip]").tooltip()` without any `doc ready block`, then there  is a chance when this code will run, there isn't any element with `rel=tooltip` in DOM yet. So `$("[rel=tooltip]")` will return an empty set and `tooltip` won't work.

An example markup when it won't work without `doc ready block`,

```
.
.
.
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("[rel=tooltip]").tooltip();
</script>
.
.
.
.
<a href="#" rel="tooltip">Something</a>
<a href="#" rel="tooltip">Something</a>
<a href="#" rel="tooltip">Something</a>
```

As browsers, interprets the markup sequentially, it will execute the js code as soon as it face it as. And when it executes the JS block here, it hasn't yet parsed the `a rel="tooltip"` tags yet, as it appears after the JS block, So they are not in DOM at that moment.

So for the above case `$("[rel=tooltip]")` is empty and hence tooltip won't work. So it's always safe to put all your JS code inside `document ready` block like

```
$(function){
    // put all your JS code here
});
```

Hope all this makes sense to you now.

Comment: @powtac, Thanks, I am also a newbie learning new things on JS everyday from SO.

Comment: +1 Great write up, learned a nice bit here. I think this is known as a *Canonical Answer* :)

Comment: Very good, but I think that it goes way too much about justifying the use of `!` yet not in a very good manner. E.g. The answer uses `!(function(){}())` when there's no outer parens in the question. Let alone you'd virtually never use 2 different `(function(){}())` as "wrappers" in a single script. May also add that it is easily fixed by placing a semi-colon after the IIFE `(function(){}());` which I find to be **much** more reasonable than casting the return value to a boolean.

Comment: So do I understand right, that if I use this I won't need jQuery noConflict modus?

Comment: @Snowball you are right. If you are only using this pattern you wont need to call noConflict . `$` will always refer to the `jQuery` object inside the IIFE.

Comment: Isn't `function(...){...}()` illegal - instead of `(function(...){...})()`?

Comment: I agree with @FabrícioMatté. Why using the not operator instead of putting a semicolon at the end? I see no apparent reason to justify that.

Comment: But it's worth noting that this works:
(function() {
    console.log('first');
    return function(a){ console.log("third",a)};
}())


(function() {
    console.log('second');
    return true
}())