# what is the meaning of "!function($){}(window.jQuery)"?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the exclamation mark do before the function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755606/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-do-before-the-function)
>   [What does !function ($) { $(function(){ }) }(window.jQuery) do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896749/what-does-function-function-window-jquery-do)

what is the meaning of "!function($){}(window.jQuery)" ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    !function($){
        //some codes here
    }(window.jQuery)
</script>
```

this js orginal code url：http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js

Comment: thanks for felix, good article

Comment: I've added a comment to the linked bootstrap question's answer as well. The "benefits of `!`" weren't sold out to me unfortunately. `=]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `!` at the beginning of the line turns your function into a function expression, it has the basically same effect¹ as the more popular [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) forms:

```
(function($){}(window.jQuery));
//which in turn is the same as
(function($){})(window.jQuery);
```

Then it is immediately invoked by passing `window.jQuery` as the `$` argument. This is useful to be able to use `$` referencing jQuery inside the function independently of the page having jQuery in [`noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) mode or not.

This approach is very common (and [recommended](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)) when developing plugins for 3rd-party use.

Little more explained: Function declarations can't be part of an expression, hence when you put the function keyword inside a `()` or precede it with a unary operator, it is interpreted as a [function expression](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/#expr-vs-decl).

¹ There is a subtle difference between `(function(){}())` and `!function(){}()`: while the parentheses simply evaluate the function to a function object in the form of a function expression, the unary `!` will do the same thing and flip the return value of the function expression. As you're not assigning this value to anything, it will simply be discarded.

It is 1 byte in load time vs the cost of a `!` operation in execution time. Both of these shouldn't take more than a fraction of milli/microsecond. It is mostly a matter of coding style preference.

Comment: So it is a trick to save a single byte (one `!` versus a `()` pair) over the more common construct?

Comment: @muistooshort Basically that, yes. Some even prefer `+function(){}()`, there are some other unary operators that can be used to make a function be part of a expression.

Comment: very detailed explanation, thank you very much.

Comment: @linjuming No problem. `=]` Felix's links are also very complete, I expected this question to have a duplicate but wasn't aware that there would be such extended answers for the same case. I guess yours is a little more special as it also includes jQuery plugin authoring,  `=]` oh wait, there is even a question for twitter bootstrap itself, wow.