# What does window.jQuery and window.$ mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Are they native properties of `window` if so why is it called jQuery, surely jquery came after javascript

**Edit**: I was looking through jquery.js and found these two lines which made me wonder about what they mean exactly. If wouldn't window.Jquery be null since JQuery is not a variable of window?

```
_jQuery = window.jQuery,

_$ = window.$,
```

Comment: I would check this article out to learn more about fundamental jQuery. http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/jquery-basics. Hope that helps!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896749/what-does-function-function-window-jquery-do

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I will pull from an article I linked to in a comment above:

> As discussed in the JavaScript Basics section, valid names in JavaScript can be pretty much anything, as long as they don't begin with a number and don't include a hyphen. So, the $ in the code above is just a shorter, more convenient name for the jQuery function; indeed, in the jQuery source code, you'll find this near the end:

```
// Expose jQuery to the global object
window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
```

> When you call the $() function and pass a selector to it, you create a
>   new jQuery object. Of course, in JavaScript, functions are objects
>   too, so that means that $ (and jQuery, of course) has properties and
>   methods, too. For example, you can refer to the $.support property for
>   information on what the current browser environment supports, and you
>   use the $.ajax method to make an AJAX request.

Basically, jQuery (when you include it) creates functions at window.$ and window.jquery. Then it sets $ equal to both of those to $ for convenience.

Comment: So to declare a global variable in javascript you must do something like `window.myVariableName` ?

Comment: A global variable can be declared as myVariable. It gets bound to window.myVariable, and can be accessed using both myVariable and window.myVariable

Answer (score 4):

[`jQuery`](http://jquery.com/) is a javascript library

> jQuery is a fast, small, and feature-rich JavaScript library. It makes
>   things like HTML document traversal and manipulation, event handling,
>   animation, and Ajax much simpler with an easy-to-use API that works
>   across a multitude of browsers. With a combination of versatility and
>   extensibility, jQuery has changed the way that millions of people
>   write JavaScript.
>   http://jquery.com/

Once you include the script on the page it will create the objects `jQuery` and `$` on the global context (window). It is not native.

These

```
_jQuery = window.jQuery,    
_$ = window.$,
```

Are internal mappings in case of overwrite. You can use the function `.noConflict` to restore the previous value of `window.$` preventing conflicts with `prototype` and other libraries

Answer (score 2):

`window` is the default / [global object](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1). Any time you [assign a value](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13.1), and aren't explicit about the object to which it will be attached then it is going to be assigned to a property of the global object unless there is a local variable to assign it to first (see section 3.b. of [PutValue](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7.2));

Any global is going to be a property of it.