# what is the use of this (function($){ })(window.jquery) in jquery

Tags: jquery, function

I have started learning Jquery and I am struck with something. I searched to learn about it but I am rather confused

```
 (function($){
    //all code here
    })(window.jquery)
```

Some documents say that **this code executes immediately**.
Some say that **it isolates the variables from the external world**. 
and some say that **it is used to prevent '$'so that it could be used as a jquery object**.

So what exactly does it do ?? Is there anything else that is done by this small arrogant code?

Comment: `immediately invoked function expression` this suits.

Comment: this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896749/what-does-function-function-window-jquery-do

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896749/what-does-function-function-window-jquery-do see the real use that twitter uses using this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(function () {
})()
```

Is a self-invoking anonymous function.

```
function ($) {

}(window.jQuery)
```

Passing, window.jQuery into that function as argument and accepting as $.

What this does is making $ an alias to window.jQuery (original jQuery Object) and hence ensuring that the $ will always refer to the jQuery object inside that closure, no matter if other library has taken that($) outside.

Check this link : [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896749/what-does-function-function-window-jquery-do)

Answer (score 1):

check below link for explanation

http://tech.myemma.com/iifes-javascript-control-variable-scope/

http://helephant.com/2008/08/23/javascript-anonymous-functions/